# How can I set a assign a subset of one Dataarray with the non-nan values from another in xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray, assign

**Setting**

I am programming a derivative function that treats points next to missing values differently (forward/backward differences instead of central ones).

**Ansatz**

In order to do that, I create a DataArray that includes all of those values and indices and calculate the values.

**Problem**

I can't find a way to create a DataArray that is filled with all values in my subselection array (the points next to missing ones, or `x_nan` in the example) where it is not NaN, and my original DataArray for all other values. The xr.where statement at the end of the example summarizes my desired behaviour quite well - but it fails due to unequal indices

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# I use the example dataarray from the xr.where() documentation
x = xr.DataArray(
    0.1 * np.arange(10),
    dims=["lat"],
    coords={"lat": np.arange(10)},
    name="sst",
)

# set some values to NaN to setup problem case
x[{'lat':slice(3,5)}] = np.nan

# create subselection array and calculate the correct values 
# (just an assignment for the sake of simplicity)  
x_nan = x.where(np.isnan(x.shift({'lat':-1})), drop=True)
x_nan[:] = np.arange(1,3.1,1)


xr.where(x.isnull(), x_nan, x)
```

This outputs:

```
ValueError: indexes along dimension 'lat' are not equal
```

I know I could use `drop=False` in my x_nan creation but, if possible, I would like to avoid that as it would complicate the calculation of the x_nan values (not shown here). Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try to explain more clearly how you want to fill missing values? maybe provide an example demonstrating the before & after? Sorry but I'm having a hard time following your desired behavior. Is this something you could do with [`ffill`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.ffill.html)/[`bfill`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.bfill.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the question! I'll clarify: using central differences missing values spread to the neighboring values. That's why I find the points next to them. Then I calculate the derivative there as the difference between that point and the non-NaN neighbor. 

**long story short**: it's not a single value but it is calculated for each point by a shift subtraction. Does that make sense?

So I think I can't use ffill or bfill

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Pablo no I’m still not following. Please edit the question to include an example and an explanation in plain language (no jargon please) that clearly walks through the procedure.